# Create an entity class

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I create an entity class in an iPhone project? Please give me a very simple example, because I'm new in iPhone development.

@Edit:: So create a Base-entity containing the properties which will be common for all the classes, then create the Observable-class and make it inherit from the Base-class. In this app we might very well be able to use the Observable as a base class for the other entities because an Observable should be able to be saves as a Dialogue for example.

Comment: I have a form. After I filled that form I need to save that data to via using object of other class.

Comment: Have you read [`this`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)?

Comment: Oki.. thanks I"ll try to read this. I need just a simple code to understand the concept. Anyway thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a very simple **tutorials**, check links bellow:

- [**iPhone Development and a sample
  Objective C Program**](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2008/03/15/iphone-development-and-a-sample-objective-c-program/)
- [**Tutorial: Creating Class Categories in Objective C**](http://iphone-obsessed.blogspot.com/2010/05/tutorial-creating-class-categories-in.html)